# Intercept data after sslstrip

Tags: man-in-the-middle, proxy, iptables, sslstrip

I am able to use sslstrip successfully as shown here https://moxie.org/software/sslstrip/

What I want to do though is be able to use sslstrip with another proxy/script to modify requests/responses AFTER they are stripped.

I can easily intercept the requests by adding a OUTPUT iptables rule, the problem is that I can't seem to read responses after they get stripped, if I use a INPUT rule, I will read the responses but they will be encrypted, I think the reason for this is because when I use an INPUT rule the result is something like this

```
HTTPS RESPONSE ----> OWN PROXY ----> SSLSTRIP ---> CLIENT
```

Hence I am seeing the https response, where as using the output rule is working fine because it would look like this:

```
CLIENT HTTP REQUEST ---> OWN PROXY ---> SSLSTRIP ----> HTTPS REQUEST
```

Now I'm not %100 sure if I'm analysing this properly.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks